# How to get a method called when the Gtk::DropDown selected item has changed?

Tags: c++, dropdown, gtkmm4

Using `gtkmm-4.0`, I defined a dropdown in my class `SomeClass` :

```cpp
auto some_dropdown = Gtk::DropDown();
auto some_model = Gtk::StringList::create({"a", "b"});
some_dropdown.set_model(some_model);
```

I am able to set/get the selected item index using `set_selected` and `get_selected`

How can I get the following callback method of `SomeClass` to be fired when the selection changed ?

```cpp
void SomeClass::some_dropdown_selected_changed(int selected){
   // do something
}
```

(I tried using `some_dropdown.property_selected().signal_changed().connect` to no avail.)

Answer (score 0):

I finally could find the correct signal to connect, which is :

```cpp
some_dropdown.property_selected().signal_changed().connect(
        sigc::bind(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &SomeClass::some_dropdown_selected_changed)));
```

Handler does not take the selected item index as a parameter:

```cpp
void SomeClass::some_dropdown_selected_changed(){
   // do something
}
```